# How to get all the totals in checkout page in Magento 2.1.8 EE

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I want to check my custom fee applied or not. So I just want to know all the totals from the quote on the checkout pages.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: whats do you mean *all the totals from the quote on the checkout pages*?

Comment: Is it possible to share of your code snipshot?

Answer (score 0):

**Get Grand Total price of items in cart.**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: What about tax, shipping charges? You have not understood my question. I want to know all the totals, not specific subtotal, grand total.